# How to count words in text and append in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, io

I'm trying to make a dictionary of frequency of words in a text but for some reason extra characters print out (I'm not sure if this is my text or if it's my code) and it doesn't successfully print out the lines or words that contain the invalid symbol! This is the code I have:

```
 def parse_documentation(filename):
    filename=open(filename, "r") 
    lines = filename.read(); 
    invalidsymbols=["`","~","!", "@","#","$"]
    for line in lines: 
        for x in invalidsymbols:
            if x in line: 
                print(line) 
                print(x) 
                print(line.replace(x, "")) 
                freq={}
            for word in line:
                count=counter(word)
        freq[word]=count
    return freq
```

Comment: Can you double-check to make sure the indentation in the code you posted is correct?

Comment: The code is not correct, e.g., counter(word) is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several flaws. I will not solve all of them but point you in the right direction.

Firstly, `read` reads the whole file as a string. I don't think that's your intention here. Use `readlines()` instead to get all lines in the file as a list.

```
def parse_documentation(filename):
    filename=open(filename, "r") 
    lines = filename.readlines(); # returns a list of all lines in file
    invalidsymbols=["`","~","!", "@","#","$"]
    freq = {} # declare this OUTSIDE of your loop.
    for line in lines:
        for letter in line:
            if letter in invalidsymbols:
                print(letter) 
                line = line.replace(letter, ""))
        print line #this should print the line without invalid symbols.

        words = line.split() # Now get the words.

        for word in line:
            count=counter(word)
            # ... Do your counter stuff here ...

    return freq
```

Second, I'm highly suspicious of the workings of your `counter` method. If your intention is to count the number of words, you could adopt this strategy:

1. Check if `word` is in `freq`.
2. If it is not in in `freq`, add it and map it to 1. Otherwise, increment the number that the `word` was previously mapped to.

This should set you on the right track.

Comment: In addition to above code `line.replace(letter,"")` will only return a new copy without [symbol=current value of `letter`]..
to print line without invalid symbols `line=line.replace(letter,"")` should be done

Comment: that looks great now :)

Comment: @adil Or better yet: `line = string.translate(line,None,deletions=invalidsymbols)` but `invalidsymbols` needs to be `"~!@..."`

Comment: "filename" is a potentially confusing name for the file object

Comment: @HennyH, usually you say `line = line.translate(None, deletions=invalidsymbols)`. I even just use `line = line.translate(None, invalidsymbols)`

Comment: @gnibbler so can I make my invalid symbols one string? instead of a list?

Comment: @user2976821, yes that's a bonus advantage

Answer (score 1):

Check this, it might be what you want. BTW, your code is not correct `Python` code. There are many issues there.

```
from collections import Counter

def parse_documentation(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as fin:
        lines = fin.read()
    #for sym in ["`","~","!","@","#","$"]: lines = lines.replace(sym,'')
    lines = lines.translate(None,"`~!@#$")    #thanks to @gnibbler's comment
    freq = Counter(lines.split())
    return freq
```

**text file:**

```
this is a text. text is that. @this #that
$this #!that is those
```

**Results:**

```
Counter({'this': 3, 'is': 3, 'that': 2, 'a': 1, 'that.': 1, 'text': 1, 'text.': 1, 'those': 1})
```

Comment: +1, but much more efficient to replace the for loop with `lines = lines.translate(None, invalidsymbols)`

Comment: @gnibbler You are correct. We were under impression to answer quickly and also thought developers will consider further improvements. We teach and learn. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

you might need.`line.split(' ')` else the for loop will loop through letters.

```
....
for word in line.split(' '):
    count=counter(word)
...
```

Comment: `line` is already single characters. the problem starts with using `.read()`